# Backbone Collection inside Collection

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I have an app in backbone where in the main app I have an event click onan element, when I click on it I want to add another app inside with its collection model... is a sorto of collection of collection.
I'm using require  the error that I retrieve is that:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addElement'
```

This is my main app:
Model:

```
define(['backbone', 'collections/element'],function(Backbone, ElementCollection){
    var DesignModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize:function(){
            console.log('Initialized Design model');
            _.defaults(this, {
                elements: new ElementCollection()
            });
        },
        addElement: function(elements, options) {
            return this.elements.add(elements, options);
        }
    });

    return DesignModel;
});
```

Collection:

```
define(['backbone', 'models/design'], function(Backbone, DesignModel){

    var designCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: DesignModel
    });

    return designCollection;
});
```

View:

```
define(['jquery' , 'backbone', 'models/design', 'collections/design', 'views/element'], 
    function($, Backbone,  DesignModel, DesignCollection, ElementView){
    var DesignView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el:$('#page'),

        initialize: function(){
            console.log('initialize DesignView');
            this.collection = new DesignCollection();
            var here = this;
            $('#insert-dynamic-element').click(function(){
                var element = new ElementView();
                here.collection.addElement(element); 
            });
        },
        render: function(){
        }
    })

    return DesignView;
});
```

App to insert inside main:
Model:

```
define(['backbone'],function(Backbone){
    var ElementModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
            name:'Design',
            type:'img'
        },
        initialize:function(){
            console.log('Initialized Element model');
        }
    });

    return ElementModel;
});
```

Collection:

```
define(['backbone', 'models/element'], function(Backbone, ElementModel){

    var elementCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: ElementModel
    });



    return elementCollection;
});
```

View

```
define(['jquery' , 'backbone', 'models/element', 'collections/element'], 
    function($, Backbone,  ElementModel, ElementCollection){
    var ElementView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el:$('#page'),

        initialize: function(){
            console.log('initialize ElementView');
            this.collection = new ElementCollection();
        },
        render: function(){
        }
    })

    return ElementView;
});
```

How can I solve this?
The error is when in the main app I click on the element and when I try to make `addElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is Available in the `DesignModel` and not in `DesignCollection`

So when you call this method, it searches for the method inside the `Collection` which is not present that leads to the error.

Also why do you want to bind the events using jQuery when you have an option of handing the same using `Native Backbone events`

To solve this add the method to the collection

```
define(['backbone', 'models/design'], function(Backbone, DesignModel){

    var designCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: DesignModel,
        addElement: function(element, options) {
            return this.add(element, options);
        }
    });

    return designCollection;
});
```

Comment: For the event is because the element is outside the element's app. What you suggest to the problem of the method? to move the method or to change the call to the method? in which mode? thanks

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri.. check updated post..You can move the mthod to the collection as you will always add the model to the collection.. Also the same can be done in a lot cleaner way

Comment: The problem is now that "Cannot call method 'add' of undefined " because elemets is declare into the model, is correct to move this into the collection?

Comment: I have copied your code and put inside the collection file, and I have cut this from model file, the other part of the file is the same like my question

Comment: It should be `return this.add(` **and not** `return this.elements.add(` if you are including the method in the collection

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri.. Glad to have been of help :)